# Disable query rewriting in where clause when saving reports

Tags: reporting-services

When I write my query in a dataset and save the rdl, SSRS rewrites the query. Is there a way to disable this via a property of the report, dataset or some other undocumented place in the rdl?

For example if my query has the following where clause:

```sql
where active = @active and (@myid IS NULL OR id = @myid)
```

It is converted to:

```sql
where ( active = @active and @myid IS NULL)  OR 
      ( active = @active and id = @myid)
```

The above is a simple example. For `where` clauses with many conditions, editing the query later on is becoming difficult.

Comment: If you're using visual query editor, try switching to text editor, I'm sure it preserves query as is

Comment: @user1578107 You should post your comment as an answer. That has always worked for me. I always avoid the query GUI in SSRS, and I don't have a problem with  any query rewriting.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using visual query editor, try switching to text editor, I'm sure it preserves query as is.